# How to receive Emails through Amazon SImple Email Service

Tags: email, email-server, amazon-ses

I would like to receive emails on Amazon SImple Email Service (SES).
There is a guide to that but I didn't understand it properly. How can I receive emails?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-managing.html

I want to use Amazon SES because my self hosted email are going into spam.

Answer (score 3):

AWS SES is intended for sending and optionally receiving email from your application (particularly an AWS hosted one, but not necessarily). This is very much reflected in how incoming mail is handled.

The [Setting Up Amazon SES Email Receiving](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-consider-use-case.html) documentation describes the options for how incoming is delivered:

> Amazon SES can provide you the email content in two ways: it can store the emails in an Amazon S3 bucket that you specify, or it can send you an Amazon SNS notification that contains a copy of the email. Amazon SES delivers you the raw, unmodified email, which is typically in Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) format. For more information about MIME format, see RFC 2045.

Ie, the options are convenient for an application to consume but essentially useless for regular users to directly interact with.

This means that if the consumer of incoming email is not your application but actual users who just want to read email, you will want to use some different solution for your your users. (Likely using a specific subdomain for incoming SES in case you need both.)

For regular users there is a wide variety of services, including WorkMail from the AWS suite and with many competing offers from other service providers.